# How to always highlight the current date on datePicker, android?

Tags: android, date, datepicker, calendar

I am using android native datePicker for selecting a date. When I open the datePicker as a dialog, I pass the date which was selected before (by using updateDate() method). And it shows me that date. Now I want that today's date was always highlighted no matter which date is selected (current date will be, for example, just red, selected one will be highlighted). Is it possible to achieve this without extending the DatePicker class? If yes can you write some hints?

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way i did this was to get today's date and then use angular ng-model to associate today's date to the input box::

```
    app.controller('DateController', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    // datePicker
    $(".datepicker").each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });

    // today's date
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }

    $scope.TodaysDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

}]);
```

And then in the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="DateController">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" required id="todaysDate" ng-model="TodaysDate" />
</div>
```

Hope you can do something similar for android.

Shaheen K